# How do I get the Ralink 3290 wireless card working on an ASUS X55C?

Tags: wireless, drivers, asus

I have ASUS X55c

tried with 10.04 and 12.04, no wifi drivers .

my network controller is Ralink corp.

Suggest how to install wifi drivers in ASUS X55C. Suggest deb packages . . .

---

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` shows...

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. 
Device [1814:3290] Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. 
Device [105b:e055] 02:00.1 Bluetooth [0d11]: Ralink corp.
Device [1814:3298] 

-- 03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Inc. 
AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet 
[1969:1091] (rev 10) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:14c7]
```

Comment: We need the hardware info for the wireless chipset: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: network controller Ralink corp. Device 3290